# Array elements of global struct in inconsistent locations

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm working on a C program that initially reads a ton of configuration information into a global structure that is then shared across all source files. The structure is defined in the following manner:

```
struct globalConfigDM {
    int controllerSocket; 
    int controllerPort;
    int dfDmToDb; 

    char **ocamsL0FitsKeywords;
    char **ocamsL0FitsTypes;
    char **ocamsL0DatabaseFields;
    int ocamsL0KeyCount;
    char ocamsL0KeyLocation[300];

    char **ocamsL1FitsKeywords;
    char **ocamsL1FitsTypes;
    char **ocamsL1DatabaseFields;
    int ocamsL1KeyCount;
    char ocamsL1KeyLocation[300];

    char **ovirsFitsKeywords;
    char **ovirsFitsTypes;
    char **ovirsDatabaseFields;
    int ovirsKeyCount;
    char ovirsKeyLocation[300];

    char databaseName[50];
    char databaseUser[50];
    char databasePassword[50];

    char pcamL0Dir[300];
    char pcamL1Dir[300];
    char mcamL0Dir[300];
    char mcamL1Dir[300];
    char scamL0Dir[300];
    char scamL1Dir[300];
    char ncamL0Dir[300];
    char ncamL1Dir[300];
    char olaSciL0Dir[300];
    char otesSciL0Dir[300];
    char ovirsSciL0Dir[300];
    char rexisSciL0Dir[300];
    char ocamsHkDir[300];
    char ovirsHkDir[300];
    char otesHkDir[300];
    char olaHkDir[300];
    char rexisHkDir[300];
};
```

In one of my source files, I declare the struct:

`struct globalConfigDM gconf;`

And in the header files of the other source files, I declare with extern:

`extern struct globalConfigDM gconf;`

When I run the program, I run into problems because the addresses of the various fields of the global structure appear differently to the main file then to the other C files, i.e. shifted over a small number of bytes. What's strange is that the address of the global struct itself remains unchanged across the same files. I've inserted a couple log lines into the program like the following:

```
logWarn("In datamoverThread(), dm.c, &gconf.databaseUser is %p", &gconf.databaseUser);
logWarn("  And &gconf is %p", &gconf);
```

I get output like the following:

```
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00] In globalConfig(), config.c, &gconf.databaseUser is 0x78395a
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00]   And &gconf is 0x783540
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00] In main(), dm.c, &gconf.databaseUser is 0x783956
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00]   And &gconf is 0x783540
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00] In runDM(), dm.c, &gconf.databaseUser is 0x783956
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00]   And &gconf is 0x783540
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00] In getNewCSock(), connect.c, &gconf.databaseUser is 0x78395a
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:38-07:00]   And &gconf is 0x783540
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:48-07:00] In datamoverThread(), dm.c, &gconf.databaseUser is 0x783956
[WSDM@2014-06-19T12:11:48-07:00]   And &gconf is 0x783540
```

The main() function is contained in dm.c, which finds `gconf.databaseUser` at **0x783956**, but the other files config.c and connect.c find the same field at **0x78395a**; however, all files are able to locate `gconf` itself at the same address.

I've spent a fair amount of time futzing around in gdb and am pretty stumped as to why this is happening. I haven't asked a question on SO before, so I apologize if I'm being vague and would be happy to provide any info that would help.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: At request, here is the entirety of the code for connect.h and dm.h, the header files for two source files which locate the struct fields at different addresses.

#### connect.h

```
#ifndef CONNECT_DM_H
#define CONNECT_DM_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <commandParser.h>
#include <spocLogger.h>

#include "prodqueue.h"
#include "config.h" // Where the struct is defined

void receiveAllCommands(void);
void getNewCsockConnection(void);
void sendStatus(void);
int sendHeartbeat(void);
void sendResults(unsigned char dest, int failure, const product *prod);

#endif
```

#### dm.h

```
#ifndef DM_H
#define DM_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <spocConfigParser.h>
#include <spocLogger.h>
#include <SpocSharedFunctions.h>

#include "oci.h"
#include "processing.h"
#include "prodqueue.h"
#include "connect.h"
#include "config.h" // Where the struct is defined

int handleOpts(int argc, char *argv[]);
void *datamoverThread(void *semNumber);
void runDatamover(int debug);
int moveFile(product *prod);
int performDatamoverWork(const product *prod, OCISvcCtx **svchp,
              OCIStmt **stmthp, OCIError **errhp);

#endif
```

Comment: Do you have any `#pragma pack`, `#pragma align` or similar directives in any of your headers ?

Comment: Also, are all of your C files compiled with the same command line options (I'm assuming you're using gcc).

Comment: @PaulR, I do not have any #pragma directives in my headers.

Comment: @DoxyLover, yes, they are all compiled together in a Makefile with `gcc -Wall -g -pthread *.c`, along with a couple of object files elsewhere in the filesystem (which don't touch `gconf`), and a number of -L, -l, -I flags.

Comment: @nbrooks3: OK - and no `__attribute__` directives ? Also I think we may need to see the full version of `globalConfigDM`, not the abridged version.

Comment: @PaulR No, nothing like that. Only the typical `#include`, include guards, and `#define`

Comment: So the structure is defined in an include file they all share?

Comment: @nbrooks3: OK - one last question and then I'm stumped - is there anything unusual in `connect.c` before the `#include` that pulls in the `struct globalConfigDM` declaration, e.g. any `#define`s or anything at all unusual ?

Comment: @Jim The structure is defined in a header and included by the header files of all source files. Each source file just includes it's corresponding header.

Comment: @PaulR all `#include`s happen in the headers. There are no `#define`s other than the include guards, and numeric/string constants.

Comment: OK - I think I need to see all of `connect.h` and the first part of `connect.c` (up to where you `#include "connect.h"`).

Comment: @PaulR, I added the contents of connect.h and dm.h. connect.c and dm.c are two source files displaying different behavior. The single `#include`s in each of the source files are always on the very first line.

Comment: I'll ask the obvious (but expect that the answer is "Yes"): Have you recompiled everything?  As an aside, the name `config.h` is used by `autoconf` and related systems to hold configuration information, so it isn't the best choice of header name, but you'd be seeing a wholly different set of problems (compilation errors) if you ran foul of this.  Have you verified that there are not two (slightly different) versions of `config.h` in the directory system?  Could someone have copied an old copy of `config.h` into one directory, and then changed one of the two versions but not both?

Comment: You have a lot of glaring repeats in the structure; you should really refactor it to avoid them.  The most striking example is `char **ocamsL0FitsKeywords; char **ocamsL0FitsTypes; char **ocamsL0DatabaseFields; int ocamsL0KeyCount; char ocamsL0KeyLocation[300];` and the version with 1 in place of 0.  This should be a structure type and your main configuration file would contain two items, `L0` and `L1` which would be the same structure.  I would not be surprised to find that reduces the code you need to manage the structure too. You also have pairs of arrays that could be treated the same way.

Comment: Along the lines of JL, dbUser isn't even a field in the version you shared. Are you sure that all compilations are up to date, and not some files refer to an old version of the structure which might explain a small 4 byte size difference if you added fields.

Comment: @gnometorule, sorry, when I originally posted the question I posted an "abridged" version of the structure to save space; `databaseUser` is the correct name. I will edit everything for consistency. @JonathanLeffler Everything has been compiled (repeatedly) and is up to date. And thanks for your refactor suggestion, I am dealing with legacy code here and I'd like to figure out why this is happening first, but will definitely take it into account once things are working!

Comment: Then I think you need to look for the second `config.h` file. I can't quite make the structure shown tie up with the offsets printed.  I see 12 bytes + 3 x (16 + 300) = 960 bytes before the database* fields, yet 0x041A = 1050 (and 0x0416 = 1046), but things don't align.  Given the addresses, I assume you're using a 32-bit build.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The issue is that this is a small self-contained module in a larger system, and these header files and the definitions of the struct are contained in the working directory. If I remove `config.h` from the working directory, I get compiler errors from all source files; none of them have the struct definition without it. I thought maybe the different files think the struct is padded differently and thus use different offsets. I can't imagine why that would be, though. There is only a single definition.

Comment: Time to insist on the MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  It should be 2 source files (dm.c and config.c) and 1 header file (config.h). The structure should be reduced (10 elements instead of 50 or so). Of course, my suspicion is you won't be able to create the MCVE, but the process of trying to create it (carving out swathes of code and still reproducing the problem; then finding out what you omit to make the problem go away) will show you the cause of the trouble.

Comment: FYI, I've run a few more tests and all elements **besides the first three `int`s** are shifted four bytes in the second file. So @JonathanLeffler, the 4-byte quantity you mentioned earlier appears to be between `dfDmToDb` and `ocamsL0FitsKeywords`. Currently setting up the MCVE, but thought I'd post this before I got to that.

Comment: Good investigating; it probably means you can chop that last 80% or more of the structure.  If you were compiling 64-bit, there'd often be 4 bytes padding between `dfDmToDb` and `ocamsL0FitsKeywords`, but the addresses you quote look like 32-bit addresses.  With a 32-bit compilation, there would not usually be any padding at that point in the structure (and you can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit object code in a single executable).  If it is 64-bit code, then I think you may have a `#pragma pack` or equivalent confusing you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, `gcc -v` gives `Target: x86_64-redhat-linux`, so I think it's be 64-bit (Though I don't know if that's the correct way of checking). I didn't write this log function, and don't have the code for it, but I imagine it might strip out leading zeros in addresses, that's why it might look like 32-bit? I wasn't even aware of the #pragma before today, so there is nothing like that, I promise.

Comment: It is 64-bit and the difference begins to look suspiciously like a difference in the packing attributes. It may be well hidden, but it is very probably there.

Comment: Consider printing `sizeof(struct globalConfigDM)` in each file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know I don't have any in this code. But, if dm.h and config.h `#include` different headers, and one of the system files included by only one of the the two had a `#pragma pack` in it, would that directive carry over to the one that included it? I ask here in case anyone knows the answer before I go digging through a ton of old system code.

Comment: Usually, system headers are written without packing, and if there is packing, it is carefully scoped not to affect other code using the system header.  I'd suspect project files before system headers, but I'd rule out neither.  You might want to use `gcc -H` (if you're using `gcc` as the compiler) to see what headers are included.

Comment: So it turns out it was a packing directive after all. Someone, in one of the old, old system headers, used `#pragma pack(1)` and didn't wrap it with `#pragma pack(push|pop)`, so it propogated through `#include`s and landed in my code. Thanks very much to those who helped. @PaulR, should have looked at the headers besides my own, you had the answer right off the bat. @JonathanLeffler thanks for the sizeof(struct) tip and all the other help. Will post in an answer once my 8 hours are up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

So it turns out it was a packing directive after all. Someone, in one of the old, old system headers, used `#pragma pack(1)` and didn't wrap it with `#pragma pack(push|pop)`, so it propogated through `#include`s and landed in my code.

Found this post that basically sums up today for me: http://binarynirvana.com/2011/07/beware-pragma-pack/

Thanks very much to those who helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is some difference in the macros of the source files before the include file containing the structure definition is included.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. If your meaning is similar to Paul's comment above, I do not have any `#define`s coming before `#include`s in any of the files.

Comment: What Jim is saying is that despite your best intentions, you have two different versions of the structure definition in use in your object code.  Depending on how big your system is, it might be quicker to remove every object file and rebuild from scratch, or it might be quicker to go hunting for stray copies of the config.h header.  But ultimately, you should do a complete rebuild to make sure you haven't got a leftover object file from a previous version of the header file.